# Is there an STL method to find all permutations of strings gives a size in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

What is the best way to find all permutations of a string specified by size in C++? I'm making the transition from python and was wondering if C++ had a builtin that could do this or if I would have to implement this from scratch. In Python I would just do

```
import itertools

print(list(itertools.permutations(string,size))
```

This is the functionality I'm trying to emulate. Any help would be greatly appreciated, couldn't really find anything other than next_permutations which doesn't have a size argument.

Comment: See [next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: What is "a string specified by size" ?

Comment: There is no such "built-in" in C++. You have [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) that can give you permutations of a whole string, but nothing that would give you all the permutations of size `n`.

Comment: @Holt, right I meant through STL. But sounds good, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not just STL, but that's as simple as it gets:

```
std::string s = ...;
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end()); // to know when you've been through all permutations
std::vector<std::string> v; // v.reserve(boost::math::factorial(s.size());
do {
    v.push_back(s); // or process in-place
} while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Comment: But probably better to do job in place instead of returning (big/huge) vector.

Comment: @Jarod42 agreed. I wanted to make it have the same effect as the list cast above, but in place would be way more efficient